# WordPress - add Database driven tables

Tags: wordpress

I'm just trying to move one of my old php sites to wordpress. As part of the site I have 'top tables' e.g. top 10 cars, listing their features etc. At the moment that all comes from a database and the HTML is generated from the data. 
So if a car soon gets a hybrid engine I just check that in the database and my web site table updates to reflect that.

This all works fine. I just don't know where to start when trying to implement something like this in wordpress. I want to keep the WP header, footer, nav... and put my table in to the content area.

Someone recommended simply copying the current generated HTML in to a new post and editing the HTML when anything changes, this sounds like a quick solution but there must be a better way of doing this.

Ideally I would want to keep my current data input pages (and separate database) for all of this 'table data' and present the out put as a post.

If anyone can point me in the right direction (key words I should search for, a guide) that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your usecase, you'll usually want to use a static page template:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Or shortcodes:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Great I'll have a look at those, I also have a search function (e.g. all cars with 3 doors and sunroof). Does that help narrow down options to shortcodes or a static template?

Comment: Either work, really. Both are a means to embed managed php code into WP. The main difference is that shortcodes can be embedded in any post or page, allowing more layout and formatting options. A page template, in contrast, amounts to a new template file for your theme, with whatever code you need in lieu of your content.